# Create new column based on grouping and conditions of other columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In the example below, there are 3 sites, each with a manager, and the ages and genders of the workers. How can I create new columns for manager age and minimum age for each gender at each site?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

site = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
manager = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
age = [24, 36, 22, 54, 28, 19, 33, 57, 26, 31, 25]
gender = ['m', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'f', 'm']

df = pd.DataFrame({'site': site,
                   'manager': manager,
                   'age': age,
                   'gender': gender})
```

I have tried this:

```
df['manager_age'] = np.select([df['manager'] == 1], [df['age']])

df['minage_m'] = df.groupby(df['site'][df['gender'] == 'm'])['age'].transform(np.min)

df['minage_f'] = df.groupby(df['site'][df['gender'] == 'f'])['age'].transform(np.min)
```

However that does not give the result I'm looking for because it doesn't populate every row. For manager_age, the first 4 rows should be 36, for minage_m the second row should be 22, etc...

| site | manager | age | gender | manager_age | minage_m | minage_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 24 | m | 0 | 22.0 | NaN |
| A | 1 | 36 | f | 36 | NaN | 36.0 |
| A | 0 | 22 | m | 0 | 22.0 | NaN |
| A | 0 | 54 | m | 0 | 22.0 | NaN |
| B | 1 | 28 | m | 28 | 28.0 | NaN |
| B | 0 | 19 | f | 0 | NaN | 19.0 |
| B | 0 | 33 | f | 0 | NaN | 19.0 |
| C | 1 | 57 | m | 57 | 25.0 | NaN |
| C | 0 | 26 | m | 0 | 25.0 | NaN |
| C | 0 | 31 | f | 0 | NaN | 31.0 |
| C | 0 | 25 | m | 0 | 25.0 | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
g = df.groupby("site", as_index=False, group_keys=False)

df["manager_age"] = g.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(np.where(x["manager"] == 1, x["age"], 0), index=x.index)
)

df["minage_m"] = g.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        np.where(mask := x["gender"].eq("m"), x.loc[mask, "age"].min(), np.nan),
        index=x.index,
    )
)

df["minage_f"] = g.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        np.where(mask := x["gender"].eq("f"), x.loc[mask, "age"].min(), np.nan),
        index=x.index,
    )
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   site  manager  age gender  manager_age  minage_m  minage_f
0     A        0   24      m            0      22.0       NaN
1     A        1   36      f           36       NaN      36.0
2     A        0   22      m            0      22.0       NaN
3     A        0   54      m            0      22.0       NaN
4     B        1   28      m           28      28.0       NaN
5     B        0   19      f            0       NaN      19.0
6     B        0   33      f            0       NaN      19.0
7     C        1   57      m           57      25.0       NaN
8     C        0   26      m            0      25.0       NaN
9     C        0   31      f            0       NaN      31.0
10    C        0   25      m            0      25.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution :

```
s = df["age"].where(df["manager"].eq(1))
managers_ages = s.groupby(df["site"]).first()
df["manager_age"] = df["site"].map(managers_ages)

gender_minages = df.groupby(["site", "gender"])["age"].transform("min")
out = df.assign(**{f"minage_{g}": gender_minages.where(df["gender"].eq(g)) for g in ["m", "f"]})
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   site  manager  age gender  manager_age  minage_m  minage_f
0     A        0   24      m      36.0000   22.0000       NaN
1     A        1   36      f      36.0000       NaN   36.0000
2     A        0   22      m      36.0000   22.0000       NaN
3     A        0   54      m      36.0000   22.0000       NaN
4     B        1   28      m      28.0000   28.0000       NaN
5     B        0   19      f      28.0000       NaN   19.0000
6     B        0   33      f      28.0000       NaN   19.0000
7     C        1   57      m      57.0000   25.0000       NaN
8     C        0   26      m      57.0000   25.0000       NaN
9     C        0   31      f      57.0000       NaN   31.0000
10    C        0   25      m      57.0000   25.0000       NaN
```

Comment: You're missing the `manager_age` column.

Comment: Yep, I updated the answer to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `merge` to get the manager_age by site
2. Use `groupby` to get the minimum age and then assign to the respective columns

```
df = df.merge(df.loc[df["manager"].eq(1),["site","age"]].rename(columns={"age":"manager_age"}), on="site")
minage = df.groupby(["site","gender"])["age"].transform("min")
df["minage_m"] = minage.where(df["gender"].eq("m"))
df["minage_f"] = minage.where(df["gender"].eq("f"))

>>> df
   site  manager  age gender  manager_age  minage_m  minage_f
0     A        0   24      m           36      22.0       NaN
1     A        1   36      f           36       NaN      36.0
2     A        0   22      m           36      22.0       NaN
3     A        0   54      m           36      22.0       NaN
4     B        1   28      m           28      28.0       NaN
5     B        0   19      f           28       NaN      19.0
6     B        0   33      f           28       NaN      19.0
7     C        1   57      m           57      25.0       NaN
8     C        0   26      m           57      25.0       NaN
9     C        0   31      f           57       NaN      31.0
10    C        0   25      m           57      25.0       NaN
```